# How can I implement a SQL Server trigger as an alternative to ON DELETE CASCADE?

Tags: sql-server, triggers, sql-server-2016

I want to use temporal table in SQL Server 2016. Currently temporal tables do not allow the use of [ON DELETE CASCADE](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt604468.aspx). How can I implement a trigger to imitate the behavior? I'd like to keep foreign keys because I use navigation properties of Entity Framework in my application.

I think an after trigger doesn't work because the delete statement doesn't work with foreign key condition.

Suppose we have the following simple situation:

[image]

1. UserRole.UserId: foreign key to User.Id
2. UserRole.RoleId: foreign key to Role.Id

If I delete the role with Id == 2 than I want to delete the second and fourth row in UserRole. How can I implement this without ON DELETE CASCADE in temporal tables?

Comment: Have you heard of the `Instead of Triggers`, google it.

Comment: Yes, but INSTEAD OF triggers are not permitted on either the current or the history table to avoid invalidating the DML logic. AFTER triggers are permitted only on the current table. They are blocked on the history table to avoid invalidating the DML logic.

Comment: Consider this - if it was trivial to implement `ON DELETE CASCADE` via something like a trigger, why would the Microsoft developers not have implemented `ON DELETE CASCADE` using such a mechanism, rather than listing it as a limitation? Any workaround you attempt is likely to run into similar restrictions.

Comment: I solved this problem on the application side. So I extended the EntityTypeConfiguration and use reflection to trigger the correct order of delete statements.

Answer (score 1):

Like I mentioned in the comments section you will need an `Instead of Trigger`, something like this......

```
CREATE TRIGGER tr_CascadeDelete_UserRole
ON [Role]
INSTEAD OF DELETE
AS
BEGIN
  SET NOCOUNT ON;

  --** Delete Rows from [UserRole] table first 
  DELETE FROM [UserRole]
  WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 
                FROM Deleted d
                WHERE d.RoleID = [UserRole].RoleID)

  --** Delete Rows from [Role] table first 
  DELETE FROM [Role]
  WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 
                FROM Deleted d
                WHERE d.RoleID = [Role].RoleID)

END
```

Comment: They're [not allowed](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/mt604468.aspx) on temporal tables